# How to deploy WSP file to github

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have written code in Visual studio and I can build the WSP from Visual studio but how to deploy WSP to github

Comment: wsp is just a file like your source code files. So you can push it to GitHub just like all other files.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the next blog for testing.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-connect-visual-studio-project-to-github/

Comment: please include the key content instead of the link